# Get result set out of a dynamically created variable in a postgres function

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to create a way of generating INSERT statements for records in any table in the DB.
I already created a function that generates the dynamic code that eventually will return the desirable result set.
However, I'm stuck in the stage of executing this variable into a result set.
This function calls my other function that creates the dynamic code variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.script_insert3(
    v_table_name character varying,
    v_where_clause character varying)
    RETURNS table(c1 text)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
declare v_cmd varchar(4000);
BEGIN         
    select dbo.script_insert2(v_table_name,v_where_clause) into v_cmd;  
    return query execute v_cmd;
END; 
$BODY$;
```

The string that is inserted into v_cmd is:

```
select 'insert into dbip(dbipserver,dbipsubnet) values(',dbo.quotenamemax(dbipserver),',',dbo.quotenamemax(dbipsubnet),');' from dbip ;
```

When I run it like that:

```
select dbo.script_insert3('dbip','');
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR:  Number of returned columns (5) does not match expected column count (1).structure of query does not match function result type
```

I tried to play with the return types - record, setof record, void...
But I can't seem to get the result I want which is:

```
insert into dbip(dbipserver,dbipsubnet) values( '10.0.0.0'  ,   '255.255.255.0' );
insert into dbip(dbipserver,dbipsubnet) values( '10.0.1.0'  ,   '255.255.255.0' );
```

Please help.